# Moving Addendum Field to the End in Biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago, chicago-style, doi, url

I am making a bibliography using `biblatex-chicago`, and I want to reference a chapter in a book by writing the chapter after the citation for the entire book, like in this example ([CMOS 14.106](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part3/ch14/psec106.html)):

Samples, John. *The Fallacy of Campaign Finance Reform*. Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 2006. See esp. chap. 7, “The Origins of Modern Campaign Finance Law.”

I thought I should try putting this information in the `addendum` field. I am including a DOI in the book citation, however, the `addendum` is placed *before* the `doi` or `url` fields, as the `biblatex-chicago` package documentation says (22). I want the `addendum` to be placed at the very *end* of the reference.

---

### Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents}{citations.bib}
    @book{Sedgwick:1997,
        Author = {Sedgwick, Eve Kosofsky},
        Title = {Novel Gazing: Queer Readings in Fiction},
        Series = {Series Q},
        Location = {Durham, NC},
        Publisher = {Duke University Press},
        Year = {1997},
        URL = {https://doi.org/10.1215/9780822382478},
        Addendum = {See esp. "Paranoid Reading and Reparative Reading; or, You're So Paranoid, You Probably Think This Introduction Is about You," 1--37.}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,isbn=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{citations.bib}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

    \begin{flushleft}

        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography

    \end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

---

### Output

The code as given is producing this:

[image: Ouput]

To clarify, I want it to be like this:

> Sedgwick, Eve Kosofsky. *Novel Gazing: Queer Readings in Fiction*. Series Q. Durham, NC: Duke University Press, 1997. https://doi.org/10.1215/9780822382478. See esp. “Paranoid Reading and Reparative Reading; or, You’re So Paranoid, You Probably Think This Introduction Is about You,” 1–37.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David Purton mentions, one way to get the desired result would be to reorder code in the bibliography drivers. (IMHO that is the semantically nicest way, but it is also the way that requires the most code.) That would require an excessive amount of code for `biblatex-chicago` if done manually and even patching is not that easy, because some of the drivers call `\printfield{addendum}` multiple times. So that is probably not the option you want to see here.

Another solution would be to use a Biber sourcemap to copy the contents of the `addendum` field to another field that we then print at the very end of the bibliography driver by patching into `finentry`. Unfortunately, `biblatex-chicago` doesn't make it easy to use a custom data model to define new fields and also already uses up all of the user-definable fields `usera` to `userf` for itself.

So my next attempt would be to try and save the contents of `addendum` at the beginning of the bibliography driver, then delete the field and then to restore and print the field at the end of the bibliography driver with `finentry`. Unfortunately, `biblatex-chicago` does not support the `begentry` bibmacro that could be used to hook into the beginning of the entry. The only bibmacro that is consistently used at the beginning of the drivers is `bibindex`. `bibindex` is a special bibmacro to index the bibliography entries that is explicitly disabled in citations, so we need to abuse `bibmacro` and work around the fact that it is disabled in citations.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,isbn=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}

% save addendum field in a macro and clear it
\newbibmacro*{begentry:fake}{%
  \savefield{addendum}{\savedaddendumfield}%
  \clearfield{addendum}}

% use bibindex has begentry hook
\renewbibmacro*{bibindex}{%
  \ifbibindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry:fake}}

% enable our hook in citations as well
\AtUsedriver{\letbibmacro{bibindex}{begentry:fake}}

% restore field contents and print them
% obeys biblatex-chicago's 'addendum' option for citations
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \ifboolexpr{togl {blx@bibliography} or togl {cms@addendum}}
    {\restorefield{addendum}{\savedaddendumfield}%
     \printfield{addendum}}
    {}%
  \finentry}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Sedgwick:1997,
  Author    = {Sedgwick, Eve Kosofsky},
  Title     = {Novel Gazing: Queer Readings in Fiction},
  Series    = {Series Q},
  Location  = {Durham, NC},
  Publisher = {Duke University Press},
  Year      = {1997},
  doi       = {10.1215/9780822382478},
  Addendum  = {See esp. \enquote{Paranoid Reading and Reparative Reading;
               or, You're So Paranoid, You Probably Think This
               Introduction Is about You,} 1--37.},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \null\vfill % only for the example

  Lorem\autocite{Sedgwick:1997}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sedgwick, Eve Kosofsky, ed. Novel Gazing: Queer Readings in Fiction. Series Q. Durham, NC: Duke University Press, 1997. https://doi.org/10.1215/9780822382478. See esp. “Paranoid Reading and Reparative Reading; or, You’re So Paranoid, You Probably Think This Introduction Is about You,” 1–37.]

---

I think David's idea with `related` is very cute and I'd like to take it a bit further. We can define a new `relatedtype` `seeesp` that can be used for references like this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,isbn=false]{biblatex-chicago}

\NewBibliographyString{seeesp}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  seeesp = {see esp\adddot},
}

\urlstyle{same}

\newbibmacro*{related:seeesp}[1]{%
  \entrydata*{#1}{%
    \ifboolexpr{   test {\ifentrytype{incollection}}
                or test {\ifentrytype{inproceedings}}}
      {\printnames{author}%
       \newcunit} 
      {}%
    \usebibmacro{title+stitle}%
    \newcunit
    \usebibmacro{chapincoll}%
    \newcunit
    \usebibmacro{volume+pages}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@suppcollection{Sedgwick:1997:paranoid,
  crossref = {Sedgwick:1997},
  author   = {Sedgwick, Eve Kosofsky},
  title    = {Paranoid Reading and Reparative Reading;
              or, You're So Paranoid, You Probably Think
              This Introduction Is about You},
  pages    = {1-37},
}
@collection{Sedgwick:1997,
  editor      = {Sedgwick, Eve Kosofsky},
  title       = {Novel Gazing: Queer Readings in Fiction},
  series      = {Series Q},
  location    = {Durham, NC},
  publisher   = {Duke University Press},
  date        = {1997},
  doi         = {10.1215/9780822382478},
  related     = {Sedgwick:1997:paranoid},
  relatedtype = {seeesp},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite[5]{Sedgwick:1997}.
Filler text \autocite[6]{Sedgwick:1997}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sedgwick, Eve Kosofsky, ed. Novel Gazing: Queer Readings in Fiction. Series Q. Durham, NC: Duke University Press, 1997. https://doi.org/10.1215/9780822382478. See esp. Paranoid Reading and Reparative Reading; or, You’re So Paranoid, You Probably Think This Introduction Is about You, 1–37.]

---

Note that technically speaking `Sedgwick:1997` is a `@collection` and not a `@book`. `@suppcollection` is the entry type for introductions and other supplementary sections of a `@collection`. 'Normal' chapters would be `@incollection`.

Comment: Wow! That is indeed complicated, but it works for me. Thank you very much!!! I have accepted your answer, but I cannot award the bounty for another 21 hours.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do this is to make use of related entries. Otherwise you need to change things in the drivers which is not always trivial for `biblatex-chicago`. (If you want the note to appear in the long citation, add `related=true` to your `biblatex` options. The default is `related=bib`.)

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Sedgwick:1997:note,
  note = {\bibstring{seeesp} \mkbibquote{Paranoid Reading and Reparative Reading; or, You're So Paranoid, You Probably Think This Introduction Is about You}, \mknormrange{1-37}},
  options = {skipbib}
}

@book{Sedgwick:1997,
  author = {Sedgwick, Eve Kosofsky},
  title = {Novel Gazing: Queer Readings in Fiction},
  series = {Series Q},
  location = {Durham, NC},
  publisher = {Duke University Press},
  date = {1997},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1215/9780822382478},
  related = {Sedgwick:1997:note},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[isbn=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{seeesp}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  seeesp = {see esp\adddot},
}

\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite[5]{Sedgwick:1997}.
Filler text \autocite[6]{Sedgwick:1997}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question! I apologize for my late response, but I did see your answer when you posted it in February. I ended up creating my bibliography manually because I frequently add short annotations to citations, and this method was too cumbersome for that. But thank you again.